# Can editText.getText().toString().trim().length() ever generate NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have many `EditText` in my app and I have used below code to check whether `EditText` is empty or not.

```
if (etEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
```

`EditText` is initialized properly but I have not added null check since I read that `getText().toString()` never returns null. Can above code ever generated `NullPointerException` assuming that `EditText` is initialized properly? I want to be safe in every situation.

Comment: if `etEditText` is null, then it would generate NPE. I think there is no other case to get NPE here

Comment: it's bad idea to check for emptyness your way. You can use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` to check for empty text.

Comment: please post your full error

Comment: @PatelPinkal I am not getting any error.i just want to be safe..just want to know can above code ever generated NullPointerException assuming that EditText is initialized properly?if yes,then in which situtaion?

Comment: @Bhuvi don't ask question in advance, when you get any kind of error then represent here and get your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a recommended way to check for a null string. Try this instead:

```
String text = etEditText.getText().toString();
if(!text.isEmpty()) {  
    ....
}
```

And the remaining part where you are asking about `NullPointerException`,
`EditText.getString()` rarely generates that but it sometimes does, so it's better to enclose the code with a try and catch block like so:

```
try {
    String text = etEditText.getText().toString();
    if(!text.isEmpty()) {   
    ...
    }
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "etEditText.getText().toString() rarely generates that but it sometimes does,"..can you tell a situaltion in which it can generate null pointer exception assuming that etEditText is initialized properly?

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to `null` check as follows.

```
if (etEditText != null) {
    String str = etEditText.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str) && (str = str.trim()).length() > 0) {
        // str will be trimmed text
        // Do your work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = textInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.isEmpty()) {
            textInputLayout.setError(message);
            hideKeyboardFrom(textInputEditText);
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
```